# How can I get all sites, that I requested in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, http

I mean all webpages that I visit. Like getting all processes throught user32 dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single way to retrieve a web site in Windows. So there is no single point at which you could grab that information.

The only common denominator that everything has (that does IP communication) is, most likely, the [Windows Socket Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock).

It might be *easier* to implement your own DNS server (or just a DNS proxy) and capture the DNS requests.